# When pipeline and foreach create value?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I'm waiting that response of this expression
`1..2 | foreach { echo $_; $_ } | foreach { $_*$_ }` 
be like

```
1
1
2
4
```

but receive

```
1
1
4
4
```

So i dont understand why is this happends.

Comment: It helps to break down each pipe apart. Beware that `echo $_` is the same as `Write-Output $_` is the same as `$_`. Your first pipe receives 1 and 2.It outputs two 1's and two 2's. Your second pipe receives those two 1's and two 2's and just doubles them.

Comment: You probably meant `1..2 | foreach {$_;$_ * $_}`

Comment: But echo located in first pipe, when $PSItem was not doubled.

Comment: A`m check how i can make necessary behavior. But i dont understand why this solution work unexprected.

Comment: `1..2 | foreach { echo $_; $_ }` is identical to this `1..2 | foreach { $_; $_ }` and outputs 1, 1, 2 and 2. That is what is getting send to the second pipe. I think you are under the impression that only the second `$_` is send to the second pipe. It isn't. 
*Everything* you output after your first pipe is send to the second pipe.

Comment: thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo sends its output to the 2nd foreach.  I think you want to use write-host, which doesn't send its output to the rest of the pipeline.  Echo would do the same thing in cmd or bash.

```
1..2 | foreach { write-host $_; $_ } | foreach { $_*$_ }

1
1
2
4
```

Comment: More succinct and to the point then what I was mumbling together in comments.